# How to query the current performance state of your GPU with CUDA?

Tags: performance, cuda, gpgpu

Preferably directly via some CUDA API, or failing that via some 3rd-party software. I'm profiling some code which is running unusually slowly and just want to check there's not something funny going on with the p-state.

Edit: on Windows 7, MSVC 2010 with NVCC

Answer (score 1):

nvidia-smi will report the p-state.

under linux:

```
man nvidia-smi
```

will give help

```
nvidia-smi -a -l |grep "Performance"
```

will output a repeating updated output of the perf state only

Under windows, find the `nvidia-smi.exe` and run it with:

```
nvidia-smi --help
```

for command-line help.

Comment: But this is only possible for professional cards. Consumer cards (anything labelled GeForce, I don't know if this includes GTX Titan since this card is a special case) only report memory usage, temperature and fan speed.

Comment: There is an nvidia-smi command available on windows as well.  You wouldn't be able to use "grep" of course, but you should be able to come up with your preferred filtering method, if you want to filter on just that one line.